# Visual Studio Tools for Git, Page not found, visual studio 2013.1

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I just encountered a strange error in the vs tools for git extension, when pressing changes I get the following error:

Page 'b38f4abc-2b2c-4e4d-a047-eaaca7514610' not found.

I've encountered this page on ms:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c/view/Discussions

They state that the only solution for fixing the problem is to reinstall 2013!

Anyone got any bright ideas how to fix this without a complete reinstall?

Comment: Okay.. So I'm forced to use TFS on my work computer, and voila the exactly same problem occurred there. So looking forward to half a day wasted on installing vs2k13, updates and addons ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I got the same issue today, and found the same page you refer to.

On page 2, "Jameson M [MSFT]" replies that you can try the following:

> If you get into this state, the first thing I would try is to run
>   'devenv /setup' from the visual studio command prompt as an admin.
>   This will force Visual Studio to rebuild the various caches for
>   finding these pages

I did exactly that, and thereafter it worked without having to re-install VS etc.

Just remember to run it as admin (I forgot the first time :-))

PS. You can typically find the VS Developer Command Prompt here:

> "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\Shortcuts\"

Comment: Thank's alot not we finally kan mark this one as closed :)

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this today, and found that I was able to fix it with my favourite "Make Visual Studio 2013 work again" trick, which is a bit less severe than the /setup flag. Find this folder:

```
C:\Users\YOUR USERNAME HERE\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0
```

In there you will find a folder called `ComponentModelCache`. This sometimes gets in a corrupted state that can cause all sorts of weird failures. (And by 'sometimes', I mean about once a week ever since I installed Update 4.)

This seems to be a folder that Visual Studio can happily rebuild from scratch as required (as the 'cache' name implies). So, make sure you don't have any instances of Visual Studio running, and then just delete that folder. (If you're feeling paranoid, move it somewhere else instead of deleting it, so that you can put it back; I've never had to do that.)

**NOTE**: just delete `ComponentModelCache`, and not the whole `12.0` folder!

Now run Visual Studio again. Everything will probably be a bit slow while it repopulates that cache, but after this, various problems may go away. The error described in this question went away, and VS's git support started working properly again, after it had been doing various bizarre things (like being unable to work out which branch I was on).

Comment: Confirmed, this is the easiest way by far. I got into this state after installing a new version of Devexpress, but any tooling can probably mess up your cache. Having VS rebuild it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I got this and was trying to fix as well; so in case this helps anyone else. I re-installed the plugin, though  this may have not mattered. While I was re-installing it dawned on me that I updated resharper while Visual Studio was still open and I had never restarted my machine. So I restarted my machine and the error went away.

Comment: This is not just git related. We are forced to use TFS @ work now, and the same error occurs there.. Booting does not help at all for me I'm afraid.... But thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the latest windows updates (as of 22/05/14), this error stopped appearing.

Comment: Hi would love to upvote you, but I cannot confirm this right now. I promise you I will mark it as an answer, when I get the chance! Thank you for your tip btw.