# Visual Studio 2013 - CodeReview doesnt show content anymore

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, azure-devops

The problem reappeared and this time, reloading the workspace doesnt help.

The shelveset of the codereview was not deleted, because my colleagues can still see the contents properly.

Any other idea what this could be?

Background:

When I open a CodeReview under "My Work", it doesnt show any content anymore. Before it did...

I didn't change any settings, and couldn't find any relevant setting (neither in VS itself nor in VS Team Services)

I am logged in to TFS, that can't be the problem.

The content it shows is just the overall comment from the Requester and the Commands "Send Comments" (disabled), "View Shelveset", "Close Review", "Actions"

I can still request CodeReviews, and my team members can see them properly.

Any idea what this could be?

Comment: Did you delete the shelveset?

Comment: How old is the code review? (in days)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty old already, I know. But I accidentally found the answer when trying to solve another issue, so I want to share it here.

The fix for this question also fixed the codereview issue. Just run 'devenv /setup' from the visual studio command prompt as an admin.

[VisualStudio Git issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22633887/visual-studio-tools-for-git-page-not-found-visual-studio-2013-1)

Answer (score 1):

Your code review was associated with a shelveset where the actual code was stored.

That shelveset has been deleted.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn´t do anything with the Shelvesets - at least not explicitly, but after deleting and reloading my workspace, everything works fine again.